# How to display data from database when JOIN table is empty?

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

This question has been bothering me ever since I started self-learning. Say I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ve_articles a 
JOIN ve_articles_categories c ON a.CategoryId=c.id 
JOIN ve_articles_comments ac ON a.id=ac.ArticleId WHERE a.UserId='$id'
```

This query will return an empty results set since there are no comments for the given article. But there is an article. So how can I still join the third table `ve_articles_comments` with the `ve_articles` and display the articles even if there are no data in `ve_articles_comments`?

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: Here's MySQL's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html).

Comment: @DarshanMehta: Thanks!! WOW!

Comment: @DarshanMehta: Please make it official I will give  you all the creds.

Comment: See OUTER JOINs. Specifically, LEFT [OUTER] JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`. [Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) MySQL's documentation, this is what it says:

> If there is no matching row for the right table in the ON or USING
>   part in a LEFT JOIN, a row with all columns set to NULL is used for
>   the right table. You can use this fact to find rows in a table that
>   have no counterpart in another table.

Try the below query:

```
SELECT * FROM ve_articles a 
LEFT JOIN ve_articles_categories c ON a.CategoryId=c.id 
LEFT JOIN ve_articles_comments ac ON a.id=ac.ArticleId 
WHERE a.UserId='$id';
```

Comment: If The RIGHT JOIN  returns all records from the right table (table2), how come I am only getting one comment from `ve_articles_comments` IN `SELECT * FROM ve_articles a LEFT JOIN ve_articles_categories c ON a.CategoryId=c.id RIGHT JOIN ve_articles_comments ac ON a.id=ac.ArticleId LEFT JOIN ve_users u ON ac.UserId=u.UserID WHERE a.UsersId='$id' GROUP BY a.id ORDER BY a.ArticleTime`?

Comment: Does the user have more than one comments? Yes, `RIGHT JOIN` does return all the rows from right table.

Comment: Yes I inserted two rows in the ve_articles_comments to test it out.

Comment: Is the problem with GROUP BY?

Comment: Yes if there's only one a.id in the result.

Comment: Ok yes there is only one a.id. But then how do I get all the comments for one article without generating one div per comment? I'm using a while statement so if I don't use GROUP BY it generates one div for each comment which I don't want.

Comment: You might want to use more than one queries in that case. First query will fetch the id (and generate the div) whereas second query will populate comments in that div.